# Call alert after response.end

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Here is my code where I am trying to show alert after response. But no os alert is showing

```
string filepath =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USPPath"].ToString() + urlPDF;
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(filepath));

if (file.Exists)
{
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "somekey", "alert('Some data missing!');", true);   
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);

Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
try
{
    Response.Flush();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "somekeyqw","alert('Some data missing!'); ", true);
   // DisplaySucessAlert(true, "Shipping Label downloaded successfully.");
   // ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Popalertxs", "normalalert();", true);
}
 finally
 {
  // DisplaySucessAlert(true, "Shipping Label downloaded successfully.");
  //  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Popalert", "normalalert();", true);
 }
}
```

I have used update panel and the html code look likes

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnuspsgenerate" class="btn-def" runat="server" Text="Download USPS label" OnClick="btnuspsgenerate_Click" />  

</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnuspsgenerate" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My pdf file gets download but not showing alert.
Here I had used many ways but not able to show alert.

Some of the code I have commented as they where not working

Comment: Check console log did you got any error ?

Comment: @AnantDabhi on console no issue is coming

Comment: Not gonna happen. You send either a file OR an updated page (containing the alert) to the client. Not both. If you want to do something clientside you'll have to do it on the button click that triggered the download and perhaps set a javascript timeout.

Answer (score 0):

When you use update panel then you can not call javascript like this ..

Try Following Code,

```
string CloseWindow;       
CloseWindow = "alert('Hello World')"; 
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanelID,UpdatePanelID.GetType(), "CloseWindow", CloseWindow, true);
```

Comment: I used to write after response.flush() ?

Comment: see ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript doesn't work with update panel so you have to use ScriptManager instead

Comment: you can try using both the response.flush and response.end after flush

Comment: Response.end will redirect it to catch and after that it will not call the further code